# MS ACCESS COMBOBOX

Tags: ms-access, combobox

good day!

i am using ms access and i want to know what will i do if i have 5 comboboxes in my form then 10 choices of name which connect in one table, how can make that if ever i select one of the name in list then the selected list will not show on the 2nd combobox list. there are 5 comboboxes in my list. look like this
[image]

Comment: Second combobox RowSource must be a query that retrieves only values that are not already in data table. Requery combobox 2 after update of combobox 1. Something like: `SELECT field FROM table1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID_FK FROM table2)` or use query wizard and build a FindUnmatched query. This has been topic of many discussions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615054/access-combobox-values-depend-on-previous-combobox. Do research and when you have specific code with issue, post question. However, to include value from current record, use a UNION query.

Comment: If you have multiple fields storing same kind of data, sounds like a non-normalized data structure.

Comment: Why redact field and table names?

Comment: You should read up on how to normalise a database. You probably need a subtable for selected employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider switching to value list and add the items the boxes using a query in VBA. Then delete and add items from other boxes when a change is made.

```
Option Explicit

' Have to use global variables because combobox.oldValue is not reliable
Dim strOld1 As String
Dim strOld2 As String
Dim strOld3 As String
Dim strOld4 As String
Dim strOld5 As String

Private Sub frmMain_Load()
    Dim rsNames as Recordset
    
    ' Get names
    Set rsNames = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset( _
        "SELECT [Names] " & _
        "FROM tblPerson")

    ' Setup recordset
    If rsNames.RecordCount  > 0 Then
        rsNames.MoveLast
        rsNames.MoveFirst
 
        ' Add names to all boxes
        Do While Not rsNames.EOF
            cboNames1.addItem rsNames.Field("Name")
            cboNames2.addItem rsNames.Field("Name")
            cboNames3.addItem rsNames.Field("Name")
            cboNames4.addItem rsNames.Field("Name")
            cboNames5.addItem rsNames.Field("Name")
            rsNames.MoveNext
    End If

    ' Dispose recordset asap
    Set rsNames = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub addRemoveItem(ByRef thisCombo As Variant, ByRef oldValue As String)
    Dim arrCombos(1 To 5) As ComboBox
    Dim otherCombo As Variant
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    
    ' Get a list of all combo boxes
    Set arrCombos(1) = Me.cboNames1
    Set arrCombos(2) = Me.cboNames2
    Set arrCombos(3) = Me.cboNames3
    Set arrCombos(4) = Me.cboNames4
    Set arrCombos(5) = Me.cboNames5
    
    ' Check for comboboxes that are not the one changed
    For Each otherCombo in arrCombos
        If otherCombo.ControlName <> thisCombo.ControlName Then
            
            ' Search for exisitng item
            IntIndex = 0
            Do While otherCombo.itemData(intIndex) <> thisCombo.Value _
            And intIndex < otherCombo.ListCount
                intIndex = intIndex + 1
            Loop

            ' Remove the found item
            otherCombo.removeItem intIndex

            ' Add unselected value back
            If oldValue <> "" Then
                otherCombo.addItem oldValue
        End if
    Next
   
    ' Change the old value to the new one
    oldValue = thisCombo.Value
 End Sub
 

Private Sub cboName1_Change()
    RemoveAddItem Me.cboName1, strOld1
End Sub

Private Sub cboName2_Change()
    RemoveAddItem Me.cboName2, strOld2
End Sub

Private Sub cboName3_Change()
    RemoveAddItem Me.cboName3, strOld3
End Sub

Private Sub cboName4_Change()
    RemoveAddItem Me.cboName4, strOld4
End Sub

Private Sub cboName5_Change()
    RemoveAddItem Me.cboName5, strOld5
End Sub
```

Sorry, I did this on a phone...

Comment: Mark as thw answer please.